# How to prevent showing console window in winrun4j

Tags: java, launcher, winrun4j

I created a desktop gui app in java and use WinRun4J to create a native Windows launcher.

my ini file looks like this

```
working.directory=.
classpath.1=oze.jar
main.class=pl.emag.oze.Run
vm.version.min=1.6
vm.location=.\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
log.level=none
java.not.found=Nie znaleziono platformy JAVA
```

I turned off console logging (log.level=none) but it keeps showing additional console window anyway
(marked red on screenshot, my app's window in background).
How to prevent it ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably used (copied) the console version of WinrRun4J. There are two .exe files (actually four, because of 32/64 bit).

WinRun4Jc.exe (or WinRun4J64c.exe) is for console applications.

WinRun4J.exe (or WinRun4J64.exe) is for Swing/GUI applications  (note the missing `c` at the end of the name)